# sql select into columns to table and columns

Tags: sql

I have a source table that is `NewID|Fruit|Apples` and I need to insert those rows into target table `OldID|Fruit|Apples`

Is there a way to select into a new table while changing columns?

Thanks!

Comment: Please give a concrete example so it is clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Also it would be better to say in which dbms you are working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming target table already exists and you want to copy all the columns

```
INSERT INTO target_table(OldID,Fruit,Apples)
SELECT NewID,Fruit,Apples FROM source_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
CREATE TABLE new_table SELECT NewID as OldID, Fruit, Apples FROM old_table
```